After creating apple device token using sonoma MacOS push notification not receiving
When i am trying to create apple device token using sonoma MacOS laptop push notification not delivering to real iPhone device
push notification properly delivering to simulator
i have created a apple device token using sonoma MacOS for real device and simulator for iPhone,
but push notification not delivering to real devices, only delivered to simulators
any idea why
